# Call matlab function from Qt using QProcess

Tags: matlab, qt, qprocess

I need to call `Matlab` function from `Qt`. I know that there are standard way to do it via `Engine`, but I was not able to connect `.lib` libraries (I think because I use Mingw compiler). So, as I understand `QProcess` is the only way to do it. I have studied examples and wrote simple program, which has one `QLineEdit`(for Matlab script) and two `QPushButton` (for send script to Matlab and read response). Here is code:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        proc = new QProcess(this);
        proc->start("\"C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2013b\\bin\\matlab.exe\"");

    }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
   {
       delete ui;
   }

  void MainWindow::on_readButton_clicked()
  {
       QByteArray dataError = proc->readAllStandardError();
       qDebug()<<dataError;
       QByteArray dataOutput = proc->readAllStandardOutput();
       qDebug()<<dataOutput;
  }

       void MainWindow::on_writeButton_clicked()
  {
       QString text = ui->textForMatlab->text();
       QByteArray script;
       script.append(text);
       qDebug()<<script;
       proc->write(script);
   }
```

When I start that program matlab.exe is launching. But when I type something in `QLineEdit` and click write button there is no response from matlab. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  QString program = "C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "yourarg" << "youragr2";// if u have any aruguments then pass here

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

if it is  not working then try with `myProcess->startDetached(program,argumets);`